# Getting different Mac address

Tags: android

I want to know the difference between MAC address of bluetooth and WIFI. Do they point to same address?
 If yes then why do we have two different approaches for getting them?

Comment: No they don't. It's different interfaces

Answer (score 1):

They are unique identifiers for the hardware, not your device, the wifi is one interface and Bluetooth is one interface and have different MAC addresses.

Consider Wikipedia for more info:
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address

Interesting part:

A media access control address (MAC address) is a unique identifier assigned to network interfaces for communications on the physical network segment. MAC addresses are used as a network address for most IEEE 802 network technologies, including Ethernet and WiFi. Logically, MAC addresses are used in the media access control protocol sublayer of the OSI reference model.

MAC addresses are most often assigned by the manufacturer of a network interface controller (NIC) and are stored in its hardware, such as the card's read-only memory or some other firmware mechanism. If assigned by the manufacturer, a MAC address usually encodes the manufacturer's registered identification number and may be referred to as the burned-in address (BIA). It may also be known as an Ethernet hardware address (EHA), hardware address or physical address. This can be contrasted to a programmed address, where the host device issues commands to the NIC to use an arbitrary address.